# Pursue new PHD program

Tags: phd

I was dismissed from vet school because a few professors felt I was not professional.  I completed almost 4 years before this decision was made.  I have tried to reapply but they won't take me back.  With all the credits and knowledge I have, I feel it would be a waste if I did not apply to another PHD program.  What should I say in a letter about why I was dismissed? Do I have a chance of getting into another program?  I have good feedback from some of the professors.

Comment: _I was dismissed from vet school because a few professors felt I was not professional._ — In what way were you not professional, the "tells tasteless jokes at social gatherings" variety, or the "falsifies data" variety?

Comment: I lost my temper with an intern and said some things I shouldn't have

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can say is the truth. Period.

Your reflection on the possible err in judgement you had may help in explaining the situation, but your use of brevitiy and candor will speak towards your professional growth.

If you were dismissed because of a moral err in judgement, you may be "SOL" as this tarnish is hard to scrub off. however, if it is simply because you are brash or brazen with your opinion, this is a correctable flaw.

be open within your letter, cite the references from the professors that support you and spend some time thinking about their position about **why** you were dismissed.